# Fresnel-Kirchhoff’s Diffraction Formula Vs. Angular Spectrum Method

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, wave-equation, greens-theorem, fresnel-integrals

I tried to work through [this](https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math262/Lectures/Lecture16.pdf) lecture and first of all, I'm curious, what is the reason for this:

> We would like to use Green’s theorem with $v(x) = G(x − x0)$

As far as I understand, Green's theorem would also work with other fundamental solutions, for example a wavefront traveling in a single direction.  Where would things go wrong when another solution is tried here?

Only thing I can imagine is that [later](https://candes.su.domains/teaching/math262/Lectures/Lecture17.pdf) it would be harder to let $R$ go to infinity and apply Sommerfeld's radiation condition.  Is this the reason?

Apart from that, someone did someone a simulation of diffraction patterns [here](https://rafael-fuente.github.io/simulating-diffraction-patterns-with-the-angular-spectrum-method-and-python.html) and the math looks way easier, it's basically just taking the FT of the field across the aperture plane and then propagating it along the $z$-axis by multiplying with $e^{-kzi}$.  Where did the all the difficulties, like applying Green's theorem, dealing with singularities and discussing convergence of the integral for $R\to\infty$, disappear in this approach?  Is the Helmholtz equation enough to guarantee a unique solution in $\mathbf{R}^3$ when the field is known along some plane?